# Mono TraceSource Switch behaviour

Tags: c#, mono

I get strange results using TraceSources in Mono:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static void show(SourceLevels l)
        {
            TraceSource t = new TraceSource("test");
            t.Switch.Level = l;
            Console.WriteLine(t.Switch.Level);
            Console.WriteLine("Critical: " + t.Switch.ShouldTrace(TraceEventType.Critical));
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + t.Switch.ShouldTrace(TraceEventType.Error));
            Console.WriteLine("Warning: " + t.Switch.ShouldTrace(TraceEventType.Warning));
            Console.WriteLine("Information: " + t.Switch.ShouldTrace(TraceEventType.Information));
            Console.WriteLine("Verbose: " + t.Switch.ShouldTrace(TraceEventType.Verbose));
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            show(SourceLevels.ActivityTracing);
            show(SourceLevels.All);
            show(SourceLevels.Critical);
            show(SourceLevels.Error);
            show(SourceLevels.Information);
            show(SourceLevels.Off);
            show(SourceLevels.Verbose);
        }
    }
}
```

Results in the following result:

```
ActivityTracing
Critical: False
Error: False
Warning: False
Information: False
Verbose: False
All
Critical: True
Error: True
Warning: True
Information: True
Verbose: True
Critical
Critical: True
Error: True
Warning: True
Information: True
Verbose: True
Error
Critical: True
Error: True
Warning: True
Information: True
Verbose: True
Information
Critical: True
Error: True
Warning: True
Information: True
Verbose: True
Off
Critical: False
Error: False
Warning: False
Information: False
Verbose: False
Verbose
Critical: True
Error: True
Warning: True
Information: True
Verbose: True
```

I expect to see some differences. But it seems all on or all off. Is this not implemented in Mono?
Or am i doing something stupid?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, you forgot to say what you think is wrong.  The SourceLevels and TraceLevel enums are distinct types.  SourceLevels describe *why* a trace event was generated, TraceLevel describes *what* event was generated.

Comment: I expect when the level is set to Information that the ShouldTrace(Verbose) returns false.

Comment: See this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.sourcelevels(v=vs.110).aspx 

ActivityTracing Allows the Stop, Start, Suspend, Transfer, and Resume events through.
All Allows all events through.
Critical Allows only Critical events through.
Error Allows Critical and Error events through.
Information Allows Critical, Error, Warning, and Information events through.
Off Does not allow any events through.
Verbose Allows Critical, Error, Warning, Information, and Verbose events through.
Warning Allows Critical, Error, and Warning events through.